# ORA-01704: string literal too long when migrating database

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

I migrate some data from a database and get it in a data.xml file
Example:

```
<insert tableName="ORG_CUSTOMER">
  <column name="My-Column" value="a very long string.."/>
</insert>
```

I then execute it with a cmd command

```
call ..\liquibase\liquibase-bin\liquibase.bat --changeLogFile=%DATA% --defaultSchemaName=NAME_DBA --defaultsFile=liquibase-local.properties update
```

And because the value sometimes is longer than 4000 characters i get the error:

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: ORA-01704: string literal too long

The column is of value clob. The autogenerated xml file contains a lot of inserts I would prefer to not edit it manually. I read something that making it a prepared statement or using pl/sql will work but I don't now how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle - by default - has a limit of 4000 byte for string literals.

If you are on 12.1 or newer you could [raise that limit to 32k](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/MAX_STRING_SIZE.html#GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C).

If you are using an old version or can't change the parameter, you can't use Liquibase's `<insert>` change.

You could try the `<loadData>` change and hope it uses a PreparedStatement, in that case the limit doesn't apply:

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_data.html

Answer (score 0):

Without the code of `liquibase.bat` it is difficult to say but.

From the [documentation on literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#sthref351):

> Text literals have properties of both the `CHAR` and `VARCHAR2` datatypes:
>
> - Within expressions and conditions, Oracle treats text literals as though they have the datatype `CHAR` by comparing them using blank-padded comparison semantics.
> - A text literal can have a maximum length of 4000 bytes.

I would guess that the script is naively converting the XML from:

```
<insert tableName="ORG_CUSTOMER">
  <column name="My-Column" value="a very long string.."/>
</insert>
```

To

```
INSERT INTO {tablename} ( "{column.name}" ) VALUES ( '{column.value}' );
```

and this will fail when the text literal has more than 4000 bytes.

To fix this you will need to edit the script to handle `CLOB` values with more than 4000 bytes (where you cannot use a text literal).

Comment: This is not an answer.